# js/app/js file net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm setting up an authentication in `laravel5` , but `js` and `css` don't work on my web page

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: what's file location from root folder?

Comment: mywebsite/ressource/js/js.app

Comment: move js folder in public folder. it will work.

Comment: mywebsite/public/js/app.js should be the root path and then you can access http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js this

Comment: i did it but it doesn't work

Comment: Now where is your js folder? and once clear browser cache and php artisan view:clear too.

Comment: it change nothing , i clear browser cache it doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem happened to me but with Laravel 6, I solved it this way

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth  //you can use vue boostrap --auth is to add the login paths and 
                      register
npm install
npm run dev
```

sorry if my English is not well written

Comment: Thank you !  I had the same with laravel 8 and with this way it solved. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

You can try referencing you app.js and app.css as follows:

```
@vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

You should be able to succesfully find these.

Answer (score 0):

in my case **npm** command pointed to  wrong place. To check that try:

```
get-command npm
```

reset its path in system variable `path` and go :

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

only then settled it all